# How to prevent html conversion of the default value translation of a field?

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n, input-formats

I have a node field which text format is set to markdown. When I translate the default value with the 18n field module using the markdown syntax, the default value is converted to html in the node add form.

How can I prevent this? I want to have the markdown syntax in the node add form.